# How to handle uber like scenario in twilio

Tags: node.js, react-native, twilio

I have an uber like scenario, where a customer can call a driver, how to handle such call in twilio. My initial attempts were as follows,

```
client.calls
    .create({
        url: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        from: '+18XXXXXXXXX', // customer
        to: '+12XXXXXXXXX' // Driver
    })
    .then(call => console.log(call.sid))
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Here, the url returns the following twiml.

```
<Response>
    <Dial>+12XXXXXXXXX</Dial>
</Response>
```

I have created a twimlBin(url in client.calls.create() function) which simply dials the driver's number. The problem is that I dont understand how wether the call is made by the  `client.calls.create()` function or the twimlBin. Also no such tutorial is present, to handle such situation.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the case of a customer calling a driver, your customer would call a Twilio number and that Twilio number would forward onto the driver's number. So, you don't need to create the call using the REST API yourself, the call will be initiated by the customer.

So, you will need a Twilio number for this. Once you have a Twilio number, you will need to set the number's handler for incoming calls. You can point that to the TwiMLBin that you've created as it will do for this first use case. Save the number and call your Twilio number, it will dial you through to the driver's number.

However, you will find that the driver's phone will show the customer's number. For privacy reasons you likely don't want that. This feature is known as [masked calling](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-masked-calling).

To mask the customer's number you can add a [`callerId` attribute to your `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid), like this:

```xml
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="{YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER}">+12XXXXXXXXX</Dial>
</Response>
```

Now when your customer calls the driver, the call will be forwarded to the driver and they will see the Twilio number.

This is great for our simple use-case here, but if you want to mask numbers for a number of drivers, then there's a bunch of work to do. Thankfully, masking numbers is such a common scenario, Twilio built a product to handle that for you. Check out [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/) and the [Twilio Proxy quick start](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/quickstart) for a tutorial on how to use it to mask numbers.